# Jenkins Workspace with Multi SCM

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins setup using Multi SCM due to the way our code is structured with two main directories in the workspace. I'd like to use static analysis, PMD or another,  but they can't find *.java due to the two main structures. How do I change the workspace or PMD so it can find my code in the two directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about PMD, but for SonarQube you can specify what code you analyze.

```
sonar.sources=./src/repo1,./src/repo2
```

You could also try checking out to a sub-directory to help with it. 
e.g. checkout to a `./src/` diretory and analyze the whole directory.